# Convert a database of lat long co-ordinates into utm data in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, utm

I'm trying to convert a csv set up as [name | lat | long] into a new csv set out as [name | easting | northing | zone | --], but it keeps coming up with the error;

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\ACES Mapping
>   Project\Data\Latlong_data\utm_request.py", line 25, in 
>       company = eachline[0] IndexError: list index out of range

I'm new to Python but had no problems when converting the original database of addresses and postcodes into lat and long with a very similar code so I'm unsure of what I've done wrong? Any help would be great thank you, I'm sorry if this is really obvious. My code is below.

```
import csv
import utm

# Here enter the lat and long column numbers;

lat_col = 1
long_col = 2

# Here enter the name of the csv file for reading (r) and writing (w)

reading = 'Eng_latlong_data.csv'
writing = 'eng_utm.csv'

rawdata = open(str(reading),'r')
csv1 = csv.reader(rawdata,delimiter='|')

newdata = open(str(writing),'w')
csv2 = csv.writer(newdata,delimiter='|')

# below code will read through each line in lat long file
# then convert to utm
# and finally write as a new line with 'company name', (easting, northing, zone number, zone letter)

for eachline in csv1:
    company = eachline[0]
    print(company)
    try:
        u = utm.from_latlon(float(eachline[1]), float(eachline[2]))
        csv.writerow([company, u[0], u[1], u[2], u[3]])
    except:
        print(' ...error')

rawdata.close()
newdata.close()
```

Comment: Are there any empty lines in your CSV file? Maybe you could put a `print(eachline)` before the `company =` assignment to get a better picture of what went wrong.

Comment: Yeah it was the empty lines you were right, I fixed it by including an if else statement, thankyou for helping

Answer (score 0):

This is my fixed code, I'm sure it could be done with less but if it helps anyone, I just had blank lines in the csv file, which was fixed using the if and else statement. The if len() > 1 runs through the code only if the length of that line is more than 1, else it doesn't.

```
    import csv
    import utm

    # Here enter the lat and long column numbers;

    lat_col = 1
    long_col = 2

    # Here enter the name of the csv file for reading (r) and writing (w)

    reading = 'SIA_latlong_data.csv'
    writing = 'SIA_utm.csv'

    rawdata = open(str(reading),'r')
    csv1 = csv.reader(rawdata,delimiter='|')

    newdata = open(str(writing),'w')
    csv2 = csv.writer(newdata,delimiter=',')

    # below code will read through each line in lat long file
    # then convert to utm
    # and finally write as a new line with 'company name', (easting, northing, zone number, zone letter)

    for eachline in csv1:
        if len(eachline) > 1:
            try:
                company = eachline[0]
                print(company)    
                u = utm.from_latlon(float(eachline[lat_col]), float(eachline[long_col]))
                csv2.writerow([str(company), str(u[0]), str(u[1]), str(u[2]), str(u[3])])
                print('written')
            except:
                print(' ...ERROR')
        else:
            print(' ...blank line')

    rawdata.close()
    newdata.close()
```